# How to grep against a list of domains without using a bash script

Tags: text-processing

I have been given a list of disposable emails and other emails that my company does not want in our mailing list and asked to remove them. I know `grep -v` or `awk !/xxx/'` but this is against a list of 1000 email domains they do not want. I could use a bash script but they are only being sorted one at a time which still leave manual sorting. Any ideas are welcone please

Comment: You haven't really explained what you are trying to do.  What do you want to grep?

Comment: So, you have a mailing list file "A". You also have a thousand-plus lines list of domains and email addresses "B" to remove from the mailing list file. You want a fairly rapid automated method to remove B from A. Is that correct? Please click [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have a file that is a mailing list.

```
$ cat mail_list
email1@domain1.com
email2@domain2.com
email3@domain3.com
email4@domain4.com
email5@domain5.com
```

You have a file that is a black list.

```
$ cat blacklist
email2@domain2.com
email4@domain4.com
```

You want to make a new mailing list file with the email addresses in the black list removed?

Using the blacklist file with `grep`:

> -f file, --file=file
>
> > Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  Empty pattern lines match every input line.  Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If
> >                  file is empty, nothing is matched.

```
$ grep -vxFf blacklist mail_list
email1@domain1.com
email3@domain3.com
email5@domain5.com
```

To make a new mailing list you would redirect this into the file like:

```
$ grep -vxFf blacklist mail_list > new_mail_list
```

Which you could then use to overwrite the old mail list

```
$ mv new_mail_list mail_list
```